# Why don't I get 'Multiple Definitions' of enum in C?

Tags: c, enums

Let's say I have three files:

```
//m.h
const int RED = 1;
//m.h ends here

//f1.c
#include "m.h"
//f1.c ends here


//f2.c
#include "m.h"
int main() {return 0;}
//f2.c ends here
```

Compiling each one separately will work, but `gcc -Wall f1.o f2.o -o prog` will produce:
 `multiple definition of 'RED'`

Now if I replace the const with:

```
//m.h
enum {RED=1} colors;
//m.h ends here
```

I'll be able to compile `prog` and use `RED` as a const and won't get any  `multiple definition` error.

Why is the behavior with `enum`s different from the one visible when you have global variables or structs with the same name in different files?

Comment: Exactly what command line gives you the error? (You should probably have the `enum` type definition in a `.h` file that's `#include`d by both `f1.c` and f2.c`; object definitions should be in `.c` files.)

Comment: That's what I meant but forgot to add. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Your command `gcc -Wall f1.o f2.o -o prog` uses existing `*.o` files, which you must have generated with an earlier `gcc -c ...` command. If you're changing your source files, it's likely that your `.o` files do not correspond to your `.c` files. Can you reproduce the problem if you compile and link in a single command? `gcc -Wall f1.c f2.c -o prog`

Comment: @KeithThompson yes, the same error appears and doesn't appear (respectively) when using `gcc -Wall f1.c f2.c -o prog`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An enumeration will not create a value in memory, which means there is no address added to the symbol table when linking.

A const variable will have an address in the compiled object, with a symbol name. When you try to link the two object files together, they each have the same symbol name "RED" pointing to different addresses, which is what causes your conflict.

Answer (score 4):

Enumeration constants are not objects, they have only a value but no allocation inside the executable. So in your second example, `RED` is just a definition of a value in each of the files. On the other hand `color` is not what you think. It is a "tentative definition" of an object named `color`. If you don't use it, it will not be allocated and everything seems fine. But it only seems so.

In your first example you have a `const`-qualified object named `RED` in each of the files. Since it is initialized this is a definition and the symbol is generated in each of the `.o` files. Thus the complaint by the linker.

Comment: So it seems (at least in a "shallow" sense) that enums are much closer to macro definitions than constants. Is that correct?

Comment: I wouldn't call them macro definitions. But the values are compile-time constants.

Comment: `enum` constants *are* constants, but a `const`-qualified object is not a "constant" in the jargon of the C standard. `enum` constants have a type (suprisingly it is `int`). Macros are completely different. They are textual replacements that *may* happen to expand to a literal, but that may also expand in something completely different (a variable, a function call or just nothing).

Comment: On a partially unrelated note, if you want to avoid the multiple definitions problem with your const int RED, bracket the header file with:
#ifndef __M_H__
#define __M_H__
[your code here]
#endif

Comment: Comments don't allow much formatting it seems. And dump the extra underscores around the sides. Did not know that until now.

Comment: @DAhrens, you'd have to put all code in backticks, then the formatting works out fine.

Comment: @DAhrens `#ifndef` wouldn't solve the multiple definitions problem for RED...`#ifndef` only works to prevent the same header file's contents from appearing twice in a single translation unit...it doesn't prevent the contents from appearing in each translation unit that `#include`s it, and it's the appearance in multiple files that causes the linking-time error. Still a good thing to do, but only a solution to multiple definitions at compile time, not a solution to multiple definitions at linking time.

Comment: @TheodoreMurdock I stand corrected! Worst part is I know this, but did not think of it as I was writing that comment.